# How to display Submenu items static?

Tags: html, css

Hi all I'm stuck at this. I have created a horizontal menu bar and it's working. 
In my code the sub menu items are displaying using the mouse hover property. But in that menu bar I want to appear the sub menu items displaying static when it is clicked. The Code is:

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <style>
     .erp-menu{
     width:100%;
     height:120px;
     background-color:#99CCFF;
     }
     .erp-menubar
    {
     width:auto;
     padding-top:15px;
     font-size:1.3em;
     margin-left:15px;
    }
    .erp-menubar ul
    {
    list-style:none;
     position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
    }
   .erp-menubar ul a
    {
    display:block;
    color:#333;
     text-decoration:none;
     padding:0 15px;
   }
   .erp-menubar ul li
   {
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   margin:0;
   padding:0
   }
   .erp-menubar ul li.current-menu-item
   {
   background:#ddd;
    }
   .erp-menubar ul li:hover
   {
   background:#f6f6f6;
   }
   .erp-menubar ul ul
   {
   width:900px;
   height:60px;
   display: none;
   position:absolute;
   top:100%;
   left:0;
   background: #CCCCCC;
   padding-top:5px;
   z-index:100;
   }
   .erp-menubar ul ul li
   {
   display:inline;
    }
   .erp-menubar ul ul a
   {
   line-height:120%;
   padding:10px 15px
   }
   .erp-menubar ul li:hover > ul
   {
   clear:both;
   display: inline-block;
    }
   </style>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div class="erp-menu">
   <div class="erp-menubar">
   <ul>
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="current-submenu"><a href="">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li class="current-submenu"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li class="current-submenu"><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li class="current-submenu"><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
            <li class="current-submenu"><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: hey, what you mean of "I want to appear the sub menu items displaying static when it is clicked"?

Comment: when i select any menu then it's sub menu have to be static..